# Метод tabs.query() расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. 
Вопрос:

1. главный: как отправить сообщение указанной вкладке, не по ее id, а привязываясь к url.
2. требуется расшифровка параметров метода `tabs.query()`;

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query( { active: true, currentWindow: true }, 
           function(tabs) { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                            tabs[0].id, 
                            { greeting: "hello" }, 
                            function(response) { console.log(response.farewell); }  );
            }
    );
   ```

Comment: что значит "требуется расшифровка параметров метода tabs.query();" ?

Comment: Мне требуется:  1. отправить сообщение указанной вкладке, не по ее id, а привязываясь к url. 2. понимание: какие есть параметры у метода tabs.query(); и что они обозначают = помогут в этой задаче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправлять сообщения к вкладкам вы можете только по их `id`.

В данном случае, вы можете получить список вкладок имеющих определенный `url`, после этого перебрать их, определяя, отправлять сообщение или нет.

Для это формируем соответствующий объект `queryInfo` (первый параметр):

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "http://www.example.com/*"}, function (tabs) {

    if (tabs.length != 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

            // Определить условие можно, или сразу всем слать
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i], {greeting: "hello"});
        }
    }
});
```

Получите все влкдаки с указанным `url` в текущем окне.

Замечу что можно отправлять как один `url` так и массив с `url`

Перебираете их и отправляете сообщения, указывая их id.

Полный список параметров функции `query` представлен [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

**UPD**: про `"permission": ["tabs"];` не забываем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40867/discussion-on-answer-by-username--tabs-query--chrome).